# Running WebBrowser separately from the main form

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have an application that runs a WebBrowser in it. This WebBrowser displays a web application that can make some long requests. As long as the request goes on the form freezes and Windows will add the "(Not Responding)" to the title.

Is it possible to let the WebBrowser load separately from the main form? So that the user can change the position of the form?

Comment: You need to make the web requests asynchronous, so they won't block the UI thread

Comment: @MalteR the web application is independant and is hosted on an iis server

Comment: The requests you make to the server needs to be async